# Make canvas object's drawn path transparent?

Tags: javascript, canvas, path, fill

I need some help with this code. There is a blue square (it is supposed to be,) but it's path is blue too!

```css
body{
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
canvas{
  background:url("https://img0.etsystatic.com/038/0/6965312/il_340x270.545626074_sflg.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onkeydown="move(event.keyCode)">
<script>
var X = 80;
var Y = 20;
function move(keyCode){
  myCanvas.fillStyle = "transperant";
  myCanvas.fillRect(X, Y, 50, 50);
  if(keyCode == 39){
    X += 5;
  }
  if(keyCode == 37){
    X -= 5;
  }
  if(keyCode == 40){
    Y += 5;
  }
  if(keyCode == 38){
    Y -= 5;
  }
  myCanvas.fillStyle = "blue";
  myCanvas.fillRect(X, Y, 50,50);
}
</script>
<canvas id="C1" width="900px" height="900px">Uhh, what?!?!</canvas>
<script>
myElement = document.getElementById("C1");
myCanvas = myElement.getContext("2d");
myCanvas.fillStyle = "transperant";
myCanvas.fillRect(80, 20, 50, 50);
  </script>
</body>
```

How do you make the path transparent/clear? I tried fillPath, but that didn't work. Maybe I was using it wrong. Please give me some help? Please also include source/example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use compositing to make new drawings "erase" existing pixels.**

The compositing mode that "erases" is `destination-out`

Example code:

```
// set compositing to use any new drawings 
// to "erase" existing drawings
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';

// draw something
// the canvas will become transparent inside that drawing
ctx.fillRect(100,100,100,100);

// reset compositing to default
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
```

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://img0.etsystatic.com/038/0/6965312/il_340x270.545626074_sflg.jpg";
function start(){

  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  // set compositing to use any new drawings 
  // to "erase" existing drawings
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';

  // draw something
  // the canvas will become transparent inside that drawing
  ctx.fillRect(100,100,100,100);

  // reset compositing to default
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over'; 

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: purple; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but that does'nt work for me. Help using your code?

Comment: I've added example code to my answer, but there isn't much to explain:  `globalCompositeOperation='destination-out'` will cause future drawings to erase current drawings.  Good luck with your project!